# Custom field is not found

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

I'm attempting to self learn Salesforce and want to add a custom field to an Account.

To achieve this I've done the following:

I've added the Total custom field to Account:

[image]

Here is the trigger:

```
trigger AccountTotalTrigger on Account (before insert) {

    List<String> accountNames = new List<String>{};
  
   //Loop through all records in the Trigger.new collection
   for(Account a: Trigger.new){
      //Concatenate the Name and billingState into the Description field
      a.Description = a.Name + ':' + a.BillingState;
   }
    
}
```

and accompanying test:

```
   @IsTest
    private with sharing class AccountsTest {
        @IsTest
        static void testAccountTriggerViaDML()
        {
                // This example is simple, illustrates how to invoke the trigger code via DML (required), 
                //   but can become complex and detract from TDD and more granularly testing of the Accounts class
                Account testAccount = new Account( Name = 'Test Account' , Total = 100 );
                insert testAccount;
                testAccount = [select Id, Name from Account where Id = :testAccount.Id];
                System.assertEquals(testAccount.Name, 'Test Account');  
        }
    
    }
```

But there is a problem on the Problems tab:

[image]
the message is: Field does not exist: Total on Account

Have I not setup the Account field correctly?

Should the test not be failing? It appears to pass:

[image: ustom]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API name of the field (database column) is `Total__c`. "Total" is just the visible label. Your Salesforce might have French/German/Spanish speakers and they'd prefer to see it translated but the code should still run OK.

Most custom things you do to SF database end with this suffix. Custom tables ("objects") like `Application__c` for example, custom fields like your `Total__c`. There are more suffixes for geolocation fields, big objects, external data... but that's battle for another day ;)

Comment: thanks, is best practice to use Total__c or change the database field column? The test now fails successfully once I fixed the naming issue.

Comment: You can't get rid of the suffix. Only standard fields (Name, Description, AccountNumber, NumberOfEMployees...) will be without suffix. It takes a while to get used to but protects you if they ever add more fields to core SF, you'll have no clashes, no side effects, time to decide whether to move to std or keep data in custom one... And if you install plugins from https://appexchange.salesforce.com/ they'll come with their own prefix so still - guaranteed there will be no clash

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you try to use custom field in apex, be sure to append the `__c` at the end.
In your case, you should be using `Total__c` instead of `Total` in your Test and Trigger wherever used.